# How do I redirect to a custom url with nginx?

Tags: redirect, nginx, config

I am trying to implement a simple custom redirect with nginx.

Incoming request:

```
http://localhost:8182/testredirect/?asd=456&aaa=ddd&trueurl=http://example.com/sdd?djdj=55
```

I would like to receive HTTP 302 redirect to `http://example.com/sdd?djdj=55`. I.e forward to anything after `trueurl` argument.

I try this:

```
location /testredirect/ {
    rewrite "\&trueurl=(.*)$" $1 redirect;
}
```

But this does not seem to work. It returns error 404.
Do I miss something?

Comment: I'd try `rewrite "\&trueurl=http://(.*)$" http://$1 redirect;` instead.  `nginx` behaves differently if the second argument of `rewrite` starts with `http://` or `https://`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @richard-smith for the helpful note about query string. Finally I ended up with the following:

```
location /testredirect/ {
    if ($args ~* "\&trueurl=http(.*)$") {
        return 302 http$1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `rewrite` regex does not operate on the query string part of the URI, so your code will never match. However, the parameter in question has already been captured as `$arg_trueurl`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_arg_) for details.

For example:

```
location /testredirect/ {
    return 302 $arg_trueurl;
}
```

Comment: This makes sense, but unfortunately `trueurl` can contain unescaped arguments too. I need to parse query string by regex to extract anything after `&trueurl=` and redirect to it.